# shorter code for a else if javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to shorten this code. It runs perfectly but it is too long. What it does is, there's a two dropdown list. The user must select on the dropdown menu, then after that a value will show in the two textboxes. the "sort-of" twist there is that, the value in the textboxes is not constant, it depends on the selected option in the menu. for example, if the user chooses Al on the first select tag and LP on the second, a value will appear on the textbox. if on the first tag it still Al but on the second its LLP, the value in textbox will change. something like that.

i'm just really starting to learn this thing. that's the reason why my coding is like that. so any suggestion is welcome.

```
$("#state").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'AL'){
        $("#entity").change(function(){
            if($(this).val() == 'LP'){
                    $('#sff').val('$186.00');
                    $('#osf').val('$119.00');
                    $("#desc").hide();
                    changeval();
            }else if($(this).val() == 'LLC'){
                $('#sff').val('$186.00');
                $('#osf').val('$99.00');
                $("#desc").show();
                $("#alLLC").show();
                changeval();
            }else if($(this).val() == 'LLP'){
                $('#sff').val('$186.00');
                $('#osf').val('$119.00');
                $("#desc").hide();
                changeval();
            }else if($(this).val() == 'NPC'){
                $('#sff').val('$186.00');
                $('#osf').val('$99.00');
                $("#desc").show();
                $("#alNPC").show();
                changeval();
            }else if($(this).val() == 'PC'){ 
                $('#sff').val('$186.00');
                $('#osf').val('$99.00');
                $("#desc").show();
                $("#alPC").show();
                changeval();
            } else{
                 $('#sff').val('$186.00');
                $('#osf').val('$99.00');
                $("#desc").show();
                $("#alPC").show();
                changeval();
            }
});
    }
    if($(this).val() == 'AK'){
        $("#entity").change(function(){
            if($(this).val() == 'LP'){
                    $('#sff').val('$50.00');
                    $('#osf').val('$119.00');
                    $("#desc").hide();
                    changeval();
            }else if($(this).val() == 'LLC'){
                $('#sff').val('$250.00');
                $('#osf').val('$99.00');
                $("#desc").hide();
                changeval();
            }else if($(this).val() == 'LLP'){
                $('#sff').val('$250.00');
                $('#osf').val('$119.00');
                $("#desc").hide();
                changeval();
            }else if($(this).val() == 'NPC'){
                $('#sff').val('$50.00');
                $('#osf').val('$99.00');
                $("#desc").hide();
                changeval();
            }else if($(this).val() == 'PC'){ 
                $('#sff').val('$250.00');
                $('#osf').val('$99.00');
                $("#desc").hide();
                changeval();
            } else{
                 $('#sff').val('$250.00');
                $('#osf').val('$99.00');
                $("#desc").hide();
                changeval();
            }
});
```

Comment: Set `$(this).val()` to a variable and use a `switch` statement. This would be a better question for [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I think questions about code that works are generally asked on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Comment: I don't think this is about code review; the OP states code works, but they are looking for a suggestion to reduce the amount of code.  This is an *approach* question.

Comment: Are you sure that code works as intended? As it is, every time the `#state` element changes you are binding an _additional_ change handler to the `#entity` element, and all of those multiple handlers will be called when `#entity` is changed. Anyway, as a general tip if you have a line of code that is repeated in every single branch of an if/else if/else block then move that line of code to before or after the whole structure - e.g., your `changeVal()` call can be after the end of the `else`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a separate function, with nestled `switch` statements.  Then return the results in an object, and then make your changes:

```
$("#state").change(function(){
        var state=$(this).val();
        $("#entity").change(function(e){
           var changestuff = updateval(state, e);
           $('#sff').val(changestuff.sff);
           $('#osf').val(changestuff.osf);
           changeval();
        })
});

function updateval(state, entity){
    switch (state){
       case 'AL':
         switch (entity){
           case 'LP':
             var details ={sff:50,osf: 119};
             break;
           case 'LLP':
             var details ={sff:250,osf: 99};
             break;
           ... // all of the rest of the options for entities
           ...
           ...
           default:
             break;
         }
       case 'AK':
         // duplicate the format for 'AL' above
       ...
       ...
       default:
         break;
    }
    return details;
}
```

Please note; I haven't tested this, but this shows you how to get it working *generally* in a function.  Now, if you expand the states to all 50 (for example), you would just add additional parts to the case functions.

Answer (score 1):

I would try separating the data from the logic, for starters:

```
$("#state").on('change', function(){
    var valuesPerState = {
        'AL': {
            'LP': {
                'sff': '$186.00',
                'osf': '$119.00',
            },
            'LLC': {
                'sff': '$186.00',
                'osf': '$99.00',
                'desc': true,
                'show': '#alLLC'
            },
            'LLP': {
                'sff': '$186.00',
                'osf': '$119.00'
            },
            'NPC': {
                'sff': '$186.00',
                'osf': '$99.00',
                'desc': true,
                'show': '#alNPC'
            },
            'PC': {
                'sff': '$186.00',
                'osf': '$99.00' ,
                'desc': true,
                'show': '#alPC'
            },
            'other': {
                'sff': '$186.00',
                'osf': '$99.00',
                'desc': true,
                'show': '#alPC'
            }
        },
        'AK': {
            'LP': {
                'sff': '$50.00',
                'osf': '$119.00'
            },
            'LLC': {
                'sff': '$250.00',
                'osf': '$99.00'
            },
            'LLP': {
                'sff': '$250.00',
                'osf': '$119.00'
            },
            'NPC': {
                'sff': '$50.00',
                'osf': '$99.00'
            },
            'PC': {
                'sff': '$250.00',
                'osf': '$99.00'
            },
            'other': {
                'sff': '$250.00',
                'osf': '$99.00'
            }
        }
    },
    state = $(this).val(),
    stateValues = valuesPerState[state];

    if(stateValues) {
        $('#entity').on('change', function(){
            var typeValues = stateValues[$(this).val()] || stateValues['other'];

            $('#sff').val(typeValues['sff']);
            $('#osf').val(typeValues['osf']);
            $("#desc").toggle(typeValues['desc']);

            if (typeValues['show']) {
                $(typeValues['show']).show();
            }
            changeval();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the inner selection statement (the one checking for LP, LLC, etc) and move it to its own function where you pass it the value of #entity.  This will clean things up for you considerably.  You can even pass in the values (just saw that those change).

Answer (score 0):

The never ending nested if statements can be avoided by using switch statements.
This will make code readable easily for other programmers and extra or nested conditions 
can be easily added.

```
$("#state").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'AL')
    {
       $("#entity").change(function(){
       switch ($(this).val())
       {
           case : 'LP'{
                    $('#sff').val('$186.00');
                    $('#osf').val('$119.00');
                    $("#desc").hide();                       
                      break;
            }
           case :  'LLC'{
                $('#sff').val('$186.00');
                $('#osf').val('$99.00');
                $("#desc").show();
                $("#alLLC").show();
                    break;
            }
           case :  'LLP'{
                $('#sff').val('$186.00');
                $('#osf').val('$119.00');
                $("#desc").hide();
                    break;
            }
           case :  'NPC'{
                $('#sff').val('$186.00');
                $('#osf').val('$99.00');
                $("#desc").show();
                $("#alNPC").show();
                    break;
            }
           case :  'PC'{ 
                $('#sff').val('$186.00');
                $('#osf').val('$99.00');
                $("#desc").show();
                $("#alPC").show();
                    break;
            }
           default {
                 $('#sff').val('$186.00');
                $('#osf').val('$99.00');
                $("#desc").show();
                $("#alPC").show();
                    break;
            }
        }//END of first Switch
    }//END of IF
    if($(this).val() == 'AK'){
        $("#entity").change(function(){
         switch ($(this).val())
       {
           case : 'LP'{
                    $('#sff').val('$50.00');
                    $('#osf').val('$119.00');
                    $("#desc").hide();
                    break;
            }
           case : 'LLC'{
                $('#sff').val('$250.00');
                $('#osf').val('$99.00');
                $("#desc").hide();
                break;
            }
           case :  'LLP'{
                $('#sff').val('$250.00');
                $('#osf').val('$119.00');
                $("#desc").hide();
                break;
            }
           case :  'NPC'{
                $('#sff').val('$50.00');
                $('#osf').val('$99.00');
                $("#desc").hide();
                break;
            }
           case :  'PC'){ 
                $('#sff').val('$250.00');
                $('#osf').val('$99.00');
                $("#desc").hide();
                break;
            } default {
                 $('#sff').val('$250.00');
                $('#osf').val('$99.00');
                $("#desc").hide();
                break;
            }
       };//END  of second switch
    }//End of IF Loop
```

Adding comments at beginning and end of conditions and what they are validating will help debugging even easier

Comment: still can consolidate a lot, if every condition calls the same `changeval();` for example, no need to duplicate it

Comment: yes indeed I culdn"t spend much time to reformat his code... will update the answer once I'm free, if the thread is not closed by then :P

Comment: updated the sample code.. No Need to add another switch over these two just use If since there are only two checks